# Extract data common in 3 different Query Statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Question is**: list if there is any model that was in the top 5 in terms of quantity, simultaneously in 2008, 2009 and 2010

I want to extract Values that is common in 3 different queries as shown below in one query:

```
Select Top 5 id_model, Count(Quantity) 
From Fact_Transactions
Where Year(date) = 2008
Group by ID_Model
Order by Count(Quantity) DESC

Select Top 5 id_model, Count(Quantity) 
From Fact_Transactions
Where Year(date) = 2009
Group by ID_Model
Order by Count(Quantity) DESC

Select Top 5 id_model, Count(Quantity) 
From Fact_Transactions
Where Year(date) = 2010
Group by ID_Model
Order by Count(Quantity) DESC
```

Sample table:

```
   Id_model         id_cust  id_loc             DATE         Quantity Total_price
    LNVO_A6600P     275262  CA-140858   2007-07-25 00:00:00.000 2   332.00
        Gi_X1       275262  CA-140858   2006-05-06 00:00:00.000 2   492.00
        Gi_SP       275261  CA-104220   2010-08-01 00:00:00.000 3   597.00
        MI_A1       275261  CA-104220   2010-03-20 00:00:00.000 1   144.00
        AC_LX1      275255  CA-120768   2009-05-30 00:00:00.000 5   1160.00
        Gi_SP       275252  US-131149   2009-10-17 00:00:00.000 2   398.00
        AC_LZ6      275250  CA-106075   2003-06-28 00:00:00.000 1   152.00
```

Comment: I think `top 5` will apply after filter common values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 3, Try this single Query

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR([date]) ORDER BY COUNT(Quantity) DESC),
       id_model,
       MyYear = YEAR([date]),
       Cnt = COUNT(Quantity)
    FROM Fact_Transactions
       WHERE YEAR(date) IN (2008,2009,2010)
       GROUP BY 
          ID_Model,
          YEAR([date])
)
SELECT
    id_model
    FROM CTE
       WHERE RN <6
          GROUP BY id_model
          HAVING COUNT(1)=3
```

Comment: Thanks sir @jayasurya !

Answer (score 1):

You can use INTERSECT operation:

```
Select Top 5 id_model,Count(Quantity) from Fact_Transactions
Where Year(date) =2008
Group by ID_Model
Order by Count(Quantity) DESC
INTERSECT
Select Top 5 id_model,Count(Quantity) from Fact_Transactions
Where Year(date) = 2009
Group by ID_Model
Order by Count(Quantity) DESC
INTERSECT
Select Top 5 id_model,Count(Quantity) from Fact_Transactions
Where Year(date) = 2010
Group by ID_Model
Order by Count(Quantity) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `inner join` will do:

```
SELECT id_model
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 5 id_model, COUNT(Quantity)
    FROM Fact_Transactions
    WHERE YEAR(date) = 2008
    GROUP BY ID_Model
    ORDER BY COUNT(Quantity) DESC
) m2008
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP 5 id_model, COUNT(Quantity)
    FROM Fact_Transactions
    WHERE YEAR(date) = 2009
    GROUP BY ID_Model
    ORDER BY COUNT(Quantity) DESC
) m2009
    ON m2008.id_model = m2009.id_mode
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP 5 id_model, COUNT(Quantity)
    FROM Fact_Transactions
    WHERE YEAR(date) = 2010
    GROUP BY ID_Model
    ORDER BY COUNT(Quantity) DESC
) m2010
    ON m2008.id_model = m2010.id_model;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from (
Select Top 5 id_model,Count(Quantity) from Fact_Transactions
Where Year(date) =2008
Group by ID_Model
Order by Count(Quantity) DESC
union all
Select Top 5 id_model,Count(Quantity) from Fact_Transactions
Where Year(date) = 2009
Group by ID_Model
Order by Count(Quantity) DESC
union all
Select Top 5 id_model,Count(Quantity) from Fact_Transactions
Where Year(date) = 2010
Group by ID_Model
Order by Count(Quantity) DESC)a
```

Answer (score 0):

### **You will get correct ans by using this..**

```
select * from (SELECT 
    TOP 5 Manufacturer_name
    FROM Fact_Transactions T1
    LEFT JOIN DIM_Model D1 ON T1.IDModel = D1.IDModel
    LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER D2  ON D2.IDManufacturer = D1.IDManufacturer
    Where DATEPART(Year,date)='2008' 
    group by Manufacturer_name, Quantity 
    Order by  SUM(Quantity ) DESC  
    intersect
SELECT  TOP 5 Manufacturer_name
    FROM Fact_Transactions T1
    LEFT JOIN DIM_Model D1 ON T1.IDModel = D1.IDModel
    LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER D2  ON D2.IDManufacturer = D1.IDManufacturer
    Where DATEPART(Year,date)='2009' 
    group by Manufacturer_name, Quantity 
    Order by  SUM(Quantity ) DESC  
    intersect
SELECT TOP 5 Manufacturer_name
    FROM Fact_Transactions T1
    LEFT JOIN DIM_Model D1 ON T1.IDModel = D1.IDModel
    LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER D2  ON D2.IDManufacturer = D1.IDManufacturer
    Where DATEPART(Year,date)='2010' 
    group by Manufacturer_name, Quantity 
    Order by  SUM(Quantity ) DESC)  as A
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for the guide, I'll take care from next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from  (SELECT
    Top 5 Model_Name
    From Fact_Transactions T1
    LEFT JOIN DIM_Model D1 ON D1.IDModel = D1.IDModel
    LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER D2  ON D2.IDManufacturer = D1.IDManufacturer
    Where DATEPART(Year,date)='2008' 
    group by Model_Name, Quantity 
    Order by  SUM(Quantity ) DESC  
    intersect
Select Top 5 Model_Name 
    From Fact_Transactions T1
    LEFT JOIN DIM_Model D1 ON D1.IDModel = D1.IDModel
    LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER D2  ON D2.IDManufacturer = D1.IDManufacturer
    Where DATEPART(Year,date)='2009' 
    group by Model_Name, Quantity 
    Order by  SUM(Quantity ) DESC 
INTERSECT
Select Top 5 Model_Name
    From Fact_Transactions T1
    LEFT JOIN DIM_Model D1 ON D1.IDModel = D1.IDModel
    LEFT JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER D2  ON D2.IDManufacturer = D1.IDManufacturer
    Where DATEPART(Year,date)='2010' 
    group by Model_Name, Quantity 
    Order by  SUM(Quantity ) DESC) as A
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

select * from (select top 5 idmodel from FACT_TRANSACTIONS where year(date)= '2008' group by idmodel order  by sum(quantity) desc 
intersect
select top 5 idmodel from FACT_TRANSACTIONS where year(date)= '2009' group by idmodel order by sum(quantity) desc 
intersect 
select top 5 idmodel from FACT_TRANSACTIONS where year(date)='2010' group by idmodel order by sum(quantity) desc ) tbl**strong text**

Comment: Welcome. Would you mind formatting your SQL query so that it’s easier to read? I’d also recommend adding some explanation of what you’re doing, why you took that approach, and why it’s an improvement over the existing answers. That will help ensure it’s useful, minimize follow-up questions, and allow it to stand on its own.